# stuck trying to find a matrix using lamda?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm stuck with the first step converting to a matrix to find a solution. I've got:

$$ 6y + (3-\lambda)x = 0 $$

$$ (4-\lambda)y + 5x  = 0 $$

I need help finding two values of $\lambda$ so that they don't have unique answers?

Comment: Is your system {6y + 3x , 4y + 5x} and you want to find the eigenvalues?

Comment: im not too sure! i dont understand what lambda does. i need to put the two equations into maths software and make it so they dont have unique answers/solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for eigenvalues, we have the matrix:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}3 & 6\\5 & 4\end{bmatrix}$$

To find the eigenvalues, we setup and solve $|A-\lambda I| = 0$

This gives us:

$$\begin{vmatrix}3-\lambda & 6\\5 & 4-\lambda\end{vmatrix}\ = 0 \rightarrow \lambda^2 - 7 \lambda - 18 = 0 \rightarrow \lambda_{1,2} = -2,9$$

If you are just looking to solve the system, we can use substitution as:

$x = -2y$, so $5(-2y) + 4 y = 0 \rightarrow y = 0 \rightarrow x = 0$

If you are looking for something else, you are going to have to clarify.

Comment: Does this find two values of lambda?

Comment: Yes, there are two distinct eigenvalues, $-2$ and $9$ from the quadratic characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @jmy: Is it clear?

Comment: yes thank you i see now! :)

Comment: @jmy: You are very welcome! Regards

Comment: Needs another TU! +1